# Angular 8 Generic component

Tags: angular, generics

I have a number of components where the logic is almost identical. For example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Rule } from '@models';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from '@core';
import { RulesSaveComponent } from './rules-save.component';
import { RuleService } from '@services';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rules',
    templateUrl: './rules.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./rules.component.scss'],
})
export class RulesComponent implements OnInit {
    rules: Rule[];

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private ruleService: RuleService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ruleService.items.subscribe(rules => (this.rules = rules));
    }

    openModal(id: number) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.message = 'Deleting a rule is irreversible. Do you wish to continue?';
        modalRef.result.then(
            () => {
                this.ruleService.delete(id);
            },
            () => {
                // Do nothing
            },
        );
    }

    openSaveForm(rule: Rule) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(RulesSaveComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.feedId = rule.feedId;
        modalRef.componentInstance.ruleId = rule.id;
        modalRef.componentInstance.modal = true;
    }
}
```

And:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Conversion } from '@models';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from '@core';
import { ConversionsSaveComponent } from './conversions-save.component';
import { ConversionService } from '@services';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conversions',
    templateUrl: './conversions.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conversions.component.scss'],
})
export class ConversionsComponent implements OnInit {
    conversions: Conversion[];

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private conversionService: ConversionService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.conversionService.items.subscribe(conversions => (this.conversions = conversions));
    }

    openModal(id: number) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.message = 'Deleting a conversion is irreversible. Do you wish to continue?';
        modalRef.result.then(
            () => {
                this.conversionService.delete(id);
            },
            () => {
                // Do nothing
            },
        );
    }

    openSaveForm(conversion: Conversion) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConversionsSaveComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.feedId = conversion.feedId;
        modalRef.componentInstance.conversionId = conversion.id;
        modalRef.componentInstance.modal = true;
    }
}
```

Or for saving details, I have:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Rule } from '@models';
import { RuleService } from '@services';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rules-save',
    templateUrl: './rules-save.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./rules-save.component.scss'],
})
export class RulesSaveComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() feedId: number;
    @Input() id: number;
    @Input() modal: boolean;
    saveForm: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    editing: boolean;

    constructor(
        private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private ruleService: RuleService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.get(this.feedId);
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() {
        return this.saveForm.controls;
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        if (this.saveForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        let rule: Rule = {
            id: this.id,
            feedId: this.feedId,
            name: this.f.name.value,
            fieldName: this.f.fieldName.value,
            filterOperator: this.f.filterOperator.value,
            expression: this.f.expression.value,
        };

        this.loading = true;
        this.ruleService[this.editing ? 'update' : 'create'](rule).subscribe(() => {
            this.reset();
            this.activeModal.close('ok');
        });
    }

    private get(feedId: number) {
        this.editing = !!this.id;

        if (this.editing) {
            this.ruleService.get(this.id).subscribe(rule => {
                this.buildForm(rule);
            });
        } else {
            var rule = new Rule();

            rule.id = 0;
            rule.feedId = feedId;

            this.buildForm(rule);
        }
    }

    private buildForm(rule: Rule) {
        this.saveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: [rule.name, Validators.required],
            fieldName: [rule.fieldName, Validators.required],
            filterOperator: [rule.filterOperator, Validators.required],
            expression: [rule.expression, Validators.required],
        });
    }

    private reset() {
        if (this.editing) return;

        this.submitted = false;
        this.saveForm.reset();
    }
}
```

and

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Conversion } from '@models';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ConversionService } from '@services';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conversions-save',
    templateUrl: './conversions-save.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conversions-save.component.scss'],
})
export class ConversionsSaveComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() feedId: number;
    @Input() id: number;
    @Input() modal: boolean;
    saveForm: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    editing: boolean;

    constructor(
        private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private conversionService: ConversionService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.get(this.feedId);
    }

    // convenience getters for easy access to form fields
    get f() {
        return this.saveForm.controls;
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        if (this.saveForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        let conversion: Conversion = {
            id: this.id,
            feedId: this.feedId,
            name: this.f.name.value,
            fieldName: this.f.fieldName.value,
            filterOperator: this.f.filterOperator.value,
            expression: this.f.expression.value,
            mathOperator: this.f.mathOperator.value,
            value: this.f.value.value,
        };

        this.loading = true;
        this.conversionService[this.editing ? 'update' : 'create'](conversion).subscribe(() => {
            this.reset();
            this.activeModal.close('ok');
        });
    }

    private get(feedId: number) {
        this.editing = !!this.id;

        if (this.editing) {
            this.conversionService.get(this.id).subscribe(conversion => {
                this.buildForm(conversion);
            });
        } else {
            var conversion = new Conversion();

            conversion.id = 0;
            conversion.feedId = feedId;

            this.buildForm(conversion);
        }
    }

    private buildForm(conversion: Conversion) {
        this.saveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: [conversion.name, Validators.required],
            fieldName: [conversion.fieldName, Validators.required],
            filterOperator: [conversion.filterOperator, Validators.required],
            expression: [conversion.expression, Validators.required],
            mathOperator: [conversion.mathOperator, Validators.required],
            value: [conversion.value, Validators.required],
        });
    }

    private reset() {
        if (this.editing) return;

        this.submitted = false;
        this.saveForm.reset();
    }
}
```

There is not much difference at all between these. Infact for each type (**list** and **save**) you can see that the changes are the same across them all. 
So in the **list** components, the changes are:

- the injected service (`RuleService` or `ConversionService`) and
- the message.

Other than that, they are identical.

For the **save** components, the changes are:

- the injected service
- the model built before saving
- the `buildForm` method for creating the form groups

So, because I have this same pattern repeated numerous times, I was hoping there might be a way to do a generic component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't like the answer I was given, so I decided to have a craic myself.
This was my solution (this is the list component):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { FilterResource } from 'src/app/_core/models/filter-resource';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from '../confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';
import { BaseSaveComponent } from './base-save.component';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/_core/services/data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-base-list',
    templateUrl: './base-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./base-list.component.scss'],
})
export class BaseListComponent<T extends FilterResource> implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { static: true }) confirmationDialog: ConfirmationDialogComponent;
    @ViewChild(BaseSaveComponent, { static: true }) saveForm: BaseSaveComponent<T>;
    items: T[];

    constructor(private dataService: DataService<T>, private deleteMessage: string) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.items.subscribe(items => (this.items = items));
    }

    openModal(id: number) {
        this.confirmationDialog.message = this.deleteMessage;
        this.confirmationDialog.open();
        this.confirmationDialog.closed.subscribe(() => {
            this.dataService.delete(id);
        });
    }

    openSaveForm(model: T) {
        this.saveForm.id = model.id;
        this.saveForm.feedId = model.feedId;
        this.saveForm.open();
    }
}
```

**FilterResource** is just this:

```js
export class FilterResource {
    public id: number;
    public feedId: number;
}
```

And my **DataService** was generic anyway:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { Resource } from '../models/resource';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService<T extends Resource> {
    items: BehaviorSubject<T[]>;

    constructor(private endpoint: string, private http: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService) {
        this.items = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);
    }

    initialize(feedId: number) {
        this.http.get<T[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/feeds/${feedId}/${this.endpoint}`).subscribe(response => {
            this.items.next(response);
        });
    }

    get(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<T>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
    }

    create(filter: T) {
        return this.http.post<T>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`, filter).pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                const message = response.message;
                const item = response.model;

                let items = this.items.value;
                items.push(item);

                this.emit(items, message);

                return response.model;
            }),
        );
    }

    update(filter: T) {
        return this.http.put<T>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`, filter).pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                const message = response.message;
                const item = response.model;

                let items = this.items.value;
                this.remove(items, filter.id);
                items.push(item);

                this.emit(items, message);

                return response.model;
            }),
        );
    }

    delete(id: number) {
        this.http.delete<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`).subscribe(response => {
            let items = this.items.value;
            items.forEach((item, i) => {
                if (item.id !== id) return;
                items.splice(i, 1);
            });

            this.emit(items, response.message);
        });
    }

    private remove(items: T[], id: number) {
        items.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (item.id !== id) return;
            items.splice(i, 1);
        });
    }

    private emit(items: T[], message: string) {
        this.items.next(items);
        this.toastr.success(message);
    }
}
```

So what this meant is that I was able to extend the component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Filter } from '@models';
import { FilterService } from '@services';
import { BaseListComponent } from '../base/base-list.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-filters',
    templateUrl: './filters.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./filters.component.scss'],
})
export class FiltersComponent extends BaseListComponent<Filter> {
    constructor(filterService: FilterService) {
        super(filterService, 'Deleting a filter is irreversible. Do you wish to continue?');
    }
}
```

I did the save in the same way.

Comment: So you'll never reference the BaseListComponent<T> directly in a template which means the base component can omit `selector: 'app-base-list'` in the component meta data, correct?

Comment: @r3plica Have you considered using interfaces to structure the code?  The interfaces could abstract the functions to help when implementing new Components or Services that may have varied need in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a service acting as a Service factory, abstracting away the actual used service since they have the same interface.

Pseudo-code:

```js
export class FactoryService {
  constructor(private rule_service: RuleService, private conversion_service: ConversionService) { }

  public correctService(name: string): MyServiceInterface {
    if(name === 'rule') {
      return this.rule_service;
    } else if (name === 'conversion') {
      return this.conversion_service
    } else {
      // Handle error...
    }
  }
}
```

where you define type `MyServiceInterface` with the proper signature so that it is clean.

And then from your code, you call `this.factory_service.correctService('rule').delete(id)` and so on.

Same thing for `buildForm`, abstract away with a factory service.